# How to join two tables by keys in django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-queryset

I have two tables with fk in one of them.

parent:

```
+----+---------+
| Id |  Name   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Test #1 |
|  2 | Test #2 |
|  3 | Test #3 |
+----+---------+
```

and child:

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| Id | Traffic | parent_id |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 |    1000 |         1 |
|  2 |    2000 |         3 |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

I need to make a queryset for my form to join tables by keys, something like:

```
select p.parent_id, p.traffic, c.name from child c, parent p where c.parent_id = p.id
```

Is there any simple way to do it?

**EDIT**:
Ok, I'll show real sample what I need to have.
There are two models Server and Resources:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    public_name = models.CharField(_(u'public name'),
                                   max_length=60,
                                   blank=False,
                                   null=False,
                                   unique=False)
    server_ident = models.CharField(_(u'server identificator'),
                                    max_length=100,
                                    blank=False,
                                    null=False,
                                    unique=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'server'
        ordering = ('public_name',)
        abstract = False

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.public_name
```

and:

```
class Resources(models.Model):
    server = models.ForeignKey(Server,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    traffic_left = models.FloatField(_(u'traffic left'),
                                     blank=False,
                                     null=False,
                                     default=0.0)
    requests_left = models.IntegerField(_(u'requests left'),
                                        blank=False,
                                        null=False,
                                        default=0)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'resources'
        abstract = False
```

Form:

```
class ProjectNewForm(forms.Form):
    servers_query = Resources.objects.all()........
    project_name = forms.CharField(required=True,
                                   min_length=2,
                                   max_length=14,
                                   label=_(u'Project name'))
    project_description = forms.CharField(required=True,
                                          max_length=2000,
                                          widget=forms.Textarea(
                                              attrs={'rows': 4}
                                          ),
                                          label=_(u'Project description'))

    server = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=servers_query,
                                    required=True,
                                    initial=0,
                                    widget=forms.Select,
                                    label=_(u'Server'))
    class Meta:
        fields = [
            'project_name',
            'project_description',
            'server',
        ]
```

I need to show on my template a selectbox ("server" field from ProjectNewForm) what contains public_name from Server model like text for option tag and Resources.server.id like a value.

Comment: Do you have a ForeignKey in the model? Show the definitions.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, sure
    class Child(models.Model):
        prnt = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: You should have posted that to start with, along with the rest of the models. But I still don't understand what you want to achieve; what are you hoping to do with this joined query?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I need to have a selectbox in my template to show parent.name like text and parent_id like value from child table

Comment: You're being too vague. Please edit the question to show an example of exactly what the output should look like.

Comment: ok, I'll change it

Comment: well, I found what can set servers_query = Resources.objects.all().values_list('server_id', 'server__public_name') and get what I want but on template I have ""option value="(1L, u'Server name')"(1L, u'Server name')/option"" insdead of ""option value="1" Server name /option"". Can't find how to do it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly I found how to do it (thanks ppl from pyha forum)

Form:

```
def get_server_list():
    return Resources.objects.all().values_list('server_id',
                                               'server__public_name')

class ProjectNewForm(forms.Form):
    project_name = forms.CharField(required=True,
                                   min_length=2,
                                   max_length=14,
                                   label=_(u'Project name'))
    project_description = forms.CharField(required=True,
                                          max_length=2000,
                                          widget=forms.Textarea(
                                              attrs={'rows': 4}
                                          ),
                                          label=_(u'Project description'))
    server = forms.Field(required=True,
                         widget=forms.Select,
                         label=_(u'Server'))

    class Meta:
        fields = [
            'project_name',
            'project_description',
            'server',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
        super(ProjectNewForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['server'] = \
            forms.ChoiceField(choices=
                              [(o[0], str(o[1])) for o in get_server_list()],
                              initial=1
                              )
```

So, now I can use server field in the template like:

```
{% render_field form.server class="form-control required" %}
```

and get well formed result:

```
<select class="form-control required" name="server">
  <option value="1">Test #1</option>
  <option value="3">Test #3</option>
</select>
```

I'm not sure, maybe there is a better solution for this kind of task, but this sample works for me.